# How to find The Docker BaseImage, The Docker Desktop how to know whats the parent of this image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

[image]

Are the `ImageId` and `SHA256` of Docker images related?

There -> my-reids.tar

```
docker inspect my-redis.tar   "ContainerConfig" -> "Image": "sha256:f37f9f678836efb038d6368daa868cc4a88c127f919e73dc8904fcb1c5308eae"
```

I can get the base image SHA256  ->  then `docker inspect --format='{{index .RepoDigests 0}}' f37`

The Docker hub cant get `ImageName` by `ImageId` or `SHA256(Digests)`?

I want to be able to identify base image(redis:7-alpine  ->  alpine:3) based on `xxx.tar`

Answer (score 0):

In docker, the image ID is the hash code of the local image JSON configuration.

If I understood correctly, you want to select the docker image based on the file inside the image. You can do that by checking the Dockerfile with hisotry command and grep on the filename:

```
docker image history --no-trunc <image> | grep <file_to_search>
```

You can list the Docker images IDs with:

```
docker images --filter "dangling=false" --format "{{.ID}}"
```